# Only one product on homepage using CMS Page in Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, content-management-system

After one product is displayed, the catalog/product/list.pthml seems not to be executed anymore.

I followed these [steps](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/20984/show-products-on-homepage-magento-1-9) 
but it doesn't work. I also have tried to change the indicated lines in list.pthml directly.

I have also ReIndexed to check if product is available, enabled etc.

Any ideas to fix this ?

Comment: There could be other reasons for this. Have you checked the logs? you can whether right click->view page source (to see if it is stopping somewhere) or directly check the PHP logs to see what error it is throwing. Also if your cache is enabled you should remove that too.

Answer (score 0):

I made first effords. I replace the indicated lines with following code:

```
<?php
                        if ($this->getChild('name.after')) {
                        $_nameAfterChildren = $this->getChild('name.after')->getSortedChildren();
                        foreach ($_nameAfterChildren as $_nameAfterChildName) {
                        $_nameAfterChild = $this->getChild('name.after')->getChild($_nameAfterChildName);
                        $_nameAfterChild->setProduct($_product);
                        echo $_nameAfterChild->toHtml();
                        }
                        }
?>
```

And at the bottom

```
<?php
if ($this->getChild('after')) {
$_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName) {
$_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
//set product collection on after blocks
$_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
}
}
?>
```

Now it's working, I get everything displayed. PHP log only have 2 "File does not exist" errors.

But now the Design is not responsive. It's not formated anymore. ???